# When sending security certificate through securityManager in HTTPS calls desired output is not received

Tags: android, ios, security, ssl, appcelerator

As per the appcelerator document [Modules.Https](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Https), when an invalid  secure certificate is passed through the security manager an error "Leaf certificate could not be verified with provided public key" is reported. But this is working fine with the first request only

When passing the valid secure certificate for the first URL request and an invalid certificate for the next URL request the error isn't been logged.

EX:

```
var url1 = "http://www.appcelerator.com/";
    var securityManager = https.createX509CertificatePinningSecurityManager([
    {
        url: url1,
        serverCertificate: "appcelerator.com.der",
    }
]);
    var httpClient = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: Success,
    onerror: failure,
    timeout : 5000,
    securityManager: securityManager,
    validatesSecureCertificate : true,
 });
httpClient.open("GET", url1); 
httpClient.send();

var url2 = "https://www.google.com/";
    var securityManager = https.createX509CertificatePinningSecurityManager([
    {
        url: url2,
        serverCertificate: "appcelerator.com.der",
    }
]);
    var httpClient = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: Success,
    onerror: failure,
    timeout : 5000,
    securityManager: securityManager,
    validatesSecureCertificate : true,
 });
httpClient.open("GET", url2); 
httpClient.send();
```

Now in the above example for the second request error method should be called because we are passing appcelerator certificate to the security manager.
But in the code it is directly calling success method with out reporting any errors.

Comment: What is your appcelerator subscription Type (i.e. indie, Pro etc)?

Comment: Appcelerator subscription is Enterprise.